# How to create repeated box(checks) image in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, image-processing

I want to create repeated box(checks) image using objective c.

[image]

Something like above image please suggest me if any possibilities of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CoreGraphic and draw this image programatically. here you have some sample code [Draw Rectangle On UIImage with Core Graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37368077/draw-rectangle-on-uiimage-with-core-graphics)